# php str_replace problem with single quote getting converted to &039

Tags: php, str-replace

I am using str_replace to replace some characters and for some reason the output converts single quotes to &039. I am not trying to replace single quotes at all. What can be causing this?

Comment: `str_replace()` doesn't encode entities (unless that is what you are replacing with). What other functions are you using?

Comment: if you don't post the code used then no one can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$v = yourstring; 
$newv = str_replace("&039", "'", $v);
```

Example:

```
$v = "Hi My Name Is &039George&039";
$newv = str_replace("&039", "'", $v);

echo $newv;
```

The Output Would Be:

```
Hi My Name Is 'George'
```

Now I just hope this helps a little and I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: and if you are using this on some kind of form and your info is getting saved with a ' as &039, then just do the reverse here before you insert into the database and it will convert &039 into ' and save it into the db.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some sort of conversion could be useful:

```
$v = $_GET['value']; 
$v1 = html_entity_decode($v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them back with something like

html_entity_decode(__("Some Text"), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")﻿